# remove hibernate logging from Dropwizard app logs

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, dropwizard

I see a lot of logs logging al the queries that make the logs  not very useful. I am trying to remove this logging from my dropwizard app logs I tried to do it through the yml file

```
logging:
  level: "DEBUG"
  loggers:
    org.hibernate: ERROR
```

And also in the logback.xml

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>
```

I also tried appenders to the yml file as console and syslog. What is the way to remove these SELECT statements from the logs?

I dont want to move the logs to another file as I do want to see the errors

The logger isnt org.hibernate but I only see "Hibernate: select * FROM ....."

Comment: Is maybe `hibernate.show_sql` property set to `true`?

Comment: this is a dropwizard app, dont think here is a config like that

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `hibernate.show_sql` to `false`

```
database:
  properties:
    hibernate.show_sql: false
```

However, this alone may not work. I upvoted the other answer as it led me to this - you do indeed have to pay attention to your configured logging levels for the hibernate package because surprisingly, if your `org.hibernate.SQL` logging level is set to `DEBUG` then this will *override* the `hibernate.show_sql: false` config and log the SQL anyway!

You need to make sure it's set to `INFO` or greater

```
logging:
  loggers:
    "org.hibernate.SQL":
      level: INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing your default application logging level to `INFO` instead

```
logging:
  level: INFO
```

and further, modify log level of a package using

```
# Sets the level for 'org.hibernate' to ERROR
loggers:
  org.hibernate: ERROR
```

[Here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml) is an effective example of the usage from dropwizard itself.

Or in your case probably the package contributing to the logs as

```
loggers:
  org.hibernate.SQL: ERROR  # note - not moving to another file either
```

Comment: Hmm... I still see select statements all over the logs. Is there a way to avoid these ? Or do I just need to move them to another file? The logger isnt org.hibernate but I only see "HIbernate: select * FROM ....."

Comment: @user_mda Did you try `org.hibernate.SQL: level: ERROR` as mentioned in the link shared in the answer? Your logs seems to be from that specific package.

Comment: Yes it gets rid of the logs logged out by the org.hibernate.SQL logger, but I am not sure where these logs are coming from as they dont show the name of the logger just "Hibernate: some sql query .. "

Comment: do you mean, you still get the logs *Hibernate: some sql query*, after updating the logger with `org.hibernate.SQL` package ?

Comment: @user_mda did you try to add in `loggers` section: `Hibernate: ERROR`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the "hibernate engine" level (in the `application.yaml` file) decreased the number of log messages:

```
loggers:
  org.hibernate.engine: error
```